# How can I split a string in Ruby on Rails and transform it into a list of values

Tags: arrays, ruby, list, split

This is the code I have, I am trying to split a string which is the result of @recipe.ingredient by this character "-" and store that value into an array. Then I would like to iterate over that array and display each ingredient as a separate line or as a list. My code does not printout anything though. It only prints the bullet point but not the values of the array. Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code and how it could work?

```
<%= @recipe.ingredient %>
  <% ingredients_array = (@recipe.ingredient).split("-")%>
  <%  ingredient_new = ingredients_array.map(&:to_s) %>
  <%= print ingredient_new %>
    <% ingredient_new.each do |ingredient|  %>
      <li><%=print ingredient %></li>
    <%end %>
```

[This is the view of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVlK8.png)

Comment: `print ingredient` prints to the standard output, but the return value is `nil`. What you probably want is `<%= ingredient %>`. The `<%= ... %>` displays the *value of the expression* not what's sent to standard output.

Comment: Thanks it works, I just had to remove the print, which is already the output of  this <%=.

I guess I should just go to bed haha

Comment: "My code does not printout anything though." – Can you show the output of the console, please? I am pretty sure it *does* print something.

Answer (score 0):

put below method to your helper file

```
def ingredients_helper(recipe)
  ingredients = recipe.ingredient
                      .split("-")
                      .map(&:to_s)
  content_tag(:ul) do    
    ingredients.each do |ingredient|
      concat(content_tag(:li, ingredient))
    end
  end
end
```

use below code to your erb file

```
<%= ingredients_helper(@recipe) %>
```